# what is this construction for : Object[]{value1,value2}?

Tags: java, object

can someone explain to me what

```
new Object[]{test_name,test_laenge};
```

means? will it just create a new one dimensional Object with 2 tuple values test_name and test_laenge?

I used this in this construction to extract values from a Database into a resultset and insert those value-tuples into a 2-column JTable...

```
((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{test_name,test_laenge});
```

but I dont really understand how this works...

Answer (score 5):

It creates an array of size two, where the entries in the array are `test_name` and `test_laenge`

It is the same as:

```
Object[] array = new Object[2];
array[0] = test_name;
array[1] = test_laenge;
((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).addRow(array);
```

The entries in the array is treated as columns and adds one row in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Object[]{test_name,test_laenge};
```

creates a new array (`Object[]`) with two elements: `test_name` and `test_laenge`.

The actual elements are the objects referenced by the two variables.

Comment: ok but how does my JTable know that it has to add a Row into my table and then add the 2 values from the new Object array into my table at the corresponding column[0] and column[1] ? and how does it know it has to insert them  at the end in the last row?

Comment: @user2774480 Why don't you read the documentation on the `addRow()` method? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29

Comment: I read it, but it wasnt said that the method passes the single values from one row one after another to the columns. I mean it could as well insert both values into colum[0] only instead :P

Comment: edit: ok I think I've understood.... it regards the values as the column values of one row ;)

Answer (score 2):

> new Object[]{test_name,test_laenge};

Creates a new array with two elements: `test_name` and `test_laenge`.

Answer (score 1):

It is creating an array that holds the type Object and initializing it with two objects.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit declaration of array of object holding two initialized elements of type object.

```
Object[] ar =new Object[]{element_1,element_2};
```

Testing `ar.length()` in this case will return 2 as the size of the initial array.
Note that this is the same as doing:

```
 Object[] arr = new Object[2];
 arr[0] = element_1;
 arr[1] = element_2
```